# How to match null values in regexp_replace functions in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to replace null values into some string when I retrieve the data from my tables. I used the `regexp_replace()` function but I don't know how to match null pattern.

I tried following queries:

```
select regexp_replace(name,NULL,'false') from student;
select regexp_replace(name,'\0','false') from student;
```

but it is not giving the expected answer.

Comment: I need match null character in regexp_replace function

Comment: What do you mean with "null character"?

Comment: column without values

Comment: A column "without values" is `NULL` and that's exactly what `coalesce(name, 'some_value')` is for.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to substitute `NULL` values for some other value in a query, you can use the `coalesce()` function:

```
SELECT coalesce(name, 'false') FROM student;
```

You can have any number of expressions as parameters in the `coalesce()` function. The expressions are evaluated from left to right until a non-NULL value is found, which is returned.

Comment: I want how to match null values in that functions.